# How to use a return value in another function as a parameter?

Tags: c++, c++17

So, I want to make two function to get the **Gross Pay** of every employee and **Total Gross Pay**,
I made a function to get the gross pay for every employee it takes 3 parameters.
This is the main;

```
int main(){
    int hours=1;
    double payRate=0.0,gross=0.0;
    while (hours >0){
        cout << "Hours: ";cin >> hours;
        cout << "Pay Rate: "; cin >> payRate;
        gross =  grossPay(hours, payRate,gross);
        cout <<gross << endl;
    }
 }
```

The program end when the user put any **negative number**,
and this the function to get the gross pay for every employee.

```
double grossPay(int h, double p,double r){
        if(h>40)
            r = h*p*1.5;
        else
            r = h*p;
    return r;
}
```

And it takes 3 parameters as an argument.
I wanna make a function that take the return of the gross pay function and save it.
How can I do that?

Comment: Arent you already saving it?

Comment: You are returning r in your function which is gross then in the your main you declare a variable to store the output of that function

Answer (score 6):

It depends on if you want to store each **Gross Pay** individually, and sum them afterwards, so that you could reuse them later; or you simply want the total of them.

- If you want to store each value individually, and sum them later, you could first declare a `std::vector`.

```
std::vector<double> grossPays;

while (hours >0)
{
    //after you got gross already
    grossPays.push_back(gross);
}
```

- If you simply want to get the total of all gross, you could:

```
double totalGross = 0.0;

while (hours >0)
{
    //after you got gross already
    totalGross += gross;
}
```

---

Also I don't see why do you have 3 parameter for your function to calculate gross pay. You could just define r in your function and return r:

```
double grossPay(int h, double p)
{
    double r;
    if(h>40) r = h*p*1.5;
    else r = h*p;
    return r;
}
```

Your `main` would be

```
gross =  grossPay(hours, payRate);
```

Or you can pass in `gross` by reference:

```
void grossPay(int h, double p, int& r)
{
    if(h>40) r = h*p*1.5;
    else r = h*p;
}
```

and your `main` would be

```
grossPay(hours, payRate, gross);
```

Answer (score 4):

```
vector<double> v;
while(hours > 0)
{
    //get inputs
    v.push_back(grossPay(hours, payRate,gross));
}
```

You can probably store all the return values in a vector.

Answer (score 2):

What do you mean by "saving it"?
You can assign the value of a function to a variable and accumulate the result:

```
double total_pay = 0.0;
while(hours > 0)
{
    //something
    total_pay = total_pay + grossPay(hours, payRate,gross);
}
cout << total_pay << endl;
```

At the end `total_pay` should have the value of all inputs together.